# Error: function "upgradeTo" will shadow "upgradeTo" When deploying using hardhat-deploy

Tags: hardhat-deploy, proxy-contracts

Error: function "upgradeTo" will shadow "upgradeTo".
Getting when I try to run hardhat deploy

deploy.js

```
module.exports = async({ getNamedAccounts, deployments }) => {
    const { deploy } = deployments;
    const { deployer } = await getNamedAccounts();

    const proxyOptionBase = { proxyContract: "ECOERC1155_ERC1967Proxy" };
    const proxyOption = {
        proxyOptionBase,
        execute: {
            methodName: "upgradeTo",
            args: [],
        },
    };
    await deploy("ECOERC1155", {
        from: deployer,
        args: [],
        log: true,
        proxy: proxyOption,
    });

};
module.exports.tags = ["ECOERC1155"];
```

Expected behavior
To deploy proxy and the implementation

versions

hardhat-deploy [^0.11.21]

hardhat ^2.12.0

nodejs 1.0.0